# Adding list of integers on C#

Tags: c#

I'm doing an exercise that requires I have someone enter a list of numbers, then when they enter "ok" the program adds the list of numbers they entered. Right now my program is returning 0 no matter how many numbers are added. I suspect the problem is with the last 3 lines of code, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Sorry about how inefficient the code is. This is only my third day learning so I'm trying to format it in a way that makes sense to me, I know there are much more efficient ways of doing this though.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool isOk = new bool();          
    bool isNumber = new bool();

    var listOfNumbers = new List<string>();
    var text = "0";

    int ignoreMe = new int();
    int sumOfNumbers = new int();
    int numberNum = new int();
    var listOfNumbersNum = new List<int>();

    while (!isOk)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number, or ok to finish");
        text = Console.ReadLine();
        bool IsNumber = Int32.TryParse(text, out ignoreMe);
        if (isNumber)
        {
            numberNum = Int32.Parse(text);
            listOfNumbersNum.Add(numberNum);
        }
        else
        {
            if (text.Equals("ok", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                sumOfNumbers = listOfNumbersNum.Sum();
                Console.WriteLine(sumOfNumbers);
                isOk = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why ignore `ignoreMe`?  That's your number.

Comment: `int.TryParse`, when successful, will set the value of `ignoreMe` to the value that the user entered, so you don't need to call `int.Parse` again - just do `listOfNumbersNum.Add(ignoreMe);`

Comment: You also never wait with `Console.ReadLine()`, so your console will likely close / finish before you see anything anyway

Comment: Don’t use `new` with ints and bools. There’s no point.

Comment: The problem here is that you're declaring a **new** variable named `IsNumber`, but you're checking the original variable `isNumber` in your `if` condition.

Comment: A few things to consider (now that your question is answered).  In general, it's best to declare a variable as close as possible to where you use it.  See how far apart your first declaration was from the second one - very hard to see.  You also don't have to initialize every variable you declare.  In fact, there's a good reason to leave them uninitialized until you are ready to really assign them with something (other than sometimes initializations can be expensive).  The compiler will pick up if you are using an uninitialized variable-it's usually a sign of a potential bug

Comment: Take a look at @m4a's answer.  See how he only declares `isOk` and the list before the While loop - they are the only things needed.  Then, he declares and immediately uses the other variables.  When you do that, a bunch of possible accidental errors just can't happen.

Comment: @maccettura: Oops, Friday afternoon.  5 minutes hadn't gone by so I fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is here:

```
bool IsNumber = Int32.TryParse(text, out ignoreMe);

if (isNumber)
{
    // rest of code omitted
```

You are creating a new variable named `IsNumber` to capture the return value of `int.TryParse`, but you're checking the value of your original variable, `isNumber` in your `if` condition.  Instead, you should just assign the result to the original variable:

```
isNumber = Int32.TryParse(text, out ignoreMe);

if (isNumber)
{
    // rest of code omitted
```

---

Note that you really don't need to declare a variable to capture this result at all, since you're only using it once. You can put the `TryParse` call inside the `if` condition:

```
if (Int32.TryParse(text, out ignoreMe))
{
    listOfNumbersNum.Add(ignoreMe);
}
// Console.ReadLine() will never return null, so you can remove that check
else if (text.Equals("ok", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // And since you only use sum once, you don't need to capture it in a variable
    Console.WriteLine("Result of sum: " + listOfNumbersNum.Sum());
    isOk = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you parse value into ignoreMe. Then you adds numberNum into list. Initial value of numberNum is 0 and it has never been changed.
This code should work for you :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool isOk = new bool();
    var listOfNumbers = new List<string>();
    string text;

    int numberNum;
    var listOfNumbersNum = new List<int>();

    while (!isOk)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number, or ok to finish");
        text = Console.ReadLine();
        bool isNumber = Int32.TryParse(text, out numberNum);
        if (isNumber)
        {
            listOfNumbersNum.Add(numberNum);
        }
        else
        {
            if (text.Equals("ok", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                int sumOfNumbers = listOfNumbersNum.Sum();
                Console.WriteLine(sumOfNumbers);
                isOk = true;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What, Can you explain what you did to solve the problem? And not just refactor the variable names

Comment: This won't even, compile. You've fixed the error which rufus explains in a comment is the `isNumber` variable.  But you declare isNumber multiple times

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have fixed

Comment: @Eugene you still havent addressed the main problem which is you providing _zero_ meaningful explanation.  `"You don't need variable ignoreMe int this case. You should parse into numberNum :"` does not really mean anything nor fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Firstly mistake in

```
bool IsNumber = Int32.TryParse(text, out ignoreMe);
if (isNumber)
```

IsNumber and isNumber is not same thing

Same code with a little bit changes

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var isOk = false;
    var listOfNumbersNum = new List<int>();

    while (!isOk)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number, or ok to finish");
        var text = Console.ReadLine();
        var isNumber = int.TryParse(text, out var numberNum);
        if (isNumber)
        {
            listOfNumbersNum.Add(numberNum);
        }
        else
        {
            if (text != null && text.Equals("ok", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var sumOfNumbers = listOfNumbersNum.Sum();
                Console.WriteLine("Result of sum: " + sumOfNumbers);
                isOk = true;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```